# Prove $\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}\frac{(-1)^{k}}{(2k+1)^{2}}=\frac{4^{n}}{2n+1}\binom{2n}{n}^{-1}\left(1+\frac{1}{3}+\cdots+\frac{1}{2n+1}\right)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series

1. show that

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}\frac{(-1)^{k}}{(2k+1)^{2}}=\frac{4^{n}}{2n+1}\binom{2n}{n}^{-1}\bigg(1+\frac{1}{3}+\cdots+\frac{1}{2n+1}\bigg)$$

I try to prove this problem, but I don’t have idea. Just I discover that the left hand side is equal to

$$\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}(1-x^{2}y^{2})^{n}dxdy$$

Can I get hint of proving this problem.

The second one is related to first one.

2. Show that

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}(-1)^{k}\frac{1}{(2k+1)^{2}}$$

is algebraic integer.

Comment: Titles should be descriptive.

Comment: Maybe try an look at this page : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}\frac{(-1)^{k}}{(2k+1)^{2}}$$
Use $\int_{0}^{\infty} x e^{-zx} dx= \frac{1}{z^2}$ ,then
$$S=\sum_{k=0}^{n} {n \choose k} (-1)^k \int_{0}^{\infty} x e^{-(2k+1)x} dx$$
$$S=\int_{0}^{\infty} x e^{-x}dx \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} {n \choose k} (-e^{-2x})^k$$
$$\implies S=\int_{0}^{\infty} x e^{-x} (1-e^{-2x})^n dx.$$
**EDIT**:Mathematica solves this integral as
$$S=\frac{ \sqrt{\pi}~\Gamma(n+1)[H_{n+1/2}+\ln 4]}{4\Gamma(n+3/2)}.$$
Noting that
$$H_{n+1/2}+2\ln 2=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{2}{2k+1}$$ and
$$\frac{\Gamma(n+1)\Gamma(1/2)}{\Gamma(n+3/2)}=\frac{2^{2n+1}}{2n+1}{2n \choose n}^{-1}$$
We finally get $$S=\frac{4^n}{2n+1}{2n \choose n}^{-1} \sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{1}{2k+1}$$

Comment: So $S=\int_{0}^{\infty}xe^{-x}(1-e^{-2x})^{n}dx=\frac{4^{n}}{2n+1}\binom{2n}{n}^{-1}\big(1+\frac{1}{3}+\cdots+\frac{1}{2n+1}\big)$ is it right?

Comment: @Hyun Seok Yi You may see my eidit now.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number#Generalized_harmonic_numbers , see subsection "Multiplication formulas" regarding the "Noting that" line.

Answer (score 7):

With $\int_{0}^{1}\ln (x)x^n dx=-1/(n+1)^2$
$$\small{\begin{align}S_n&=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}\frac{(-1)^k}{(2k+1)^2}\\&=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}(-1)^{k}\int_{0}^{1}\ln\left(x\right)x^{2k}dx\\&=-\int_{0}^{1}\ln\left(x\right)\left(\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}(-1)^{k}x^{2k}\right)dx\\&=-\int_{0}^{1}\ln\left(x\right)\left(1-x^{2}\right)^{n}dx\tag{1}\end{align}}$$
Applying Integration by parts, $$\small{\begin{align}S_n&=-2n\int_{0}^{1}\left(\ln\left(x\right)-1\right)\left(1-x^{2}\right)^{n-1}\underbrace{x^{2}}_{x^2-1+1}dx\\&=2n\left[\int_{0}^{1}\left(\ln\left(x\right)-1\right)\left(1-x^{2}\right)^{n}dx-\int_{0}^{1}\left(\ln\left(x\right)-1\right)\left(1-x^{2}\right)^{n-1}dx\right]\\&=2n\left[\int_{0}^{1}\ln\left(x\right)\left(1-x^{2}\right)^{n}dx-\int_{0}^{1}\ln\left(x\right)\left(1-x^{2}\right)^{n-1}dx+\int_{0}^{1}\left(\left(1-x^{2}\right)^{n-1}-\left(1-x^{2}\right)^{n}\right)dx\right]\\&=2n\left[ -S_{n}+S_{n-1}+\int_{0}^{1}\left(\left(1-x^{2}\right)^{n-1}-\left(1-x^{2}\right)^{n}\right)dx\right]\\&=2n\left[-S_{n}+S_{n-1}+\frac{4^{n}n!^{2}}{\left(2n+1\right)!}\frac{1}{2n}\right]\tag{2}\end{align}}$$

The integral [$\int_0^{1}(1-x^2)^ndx=2^{2n}n!^2/(2n+1)!$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2162309/find-the-value-of-a-given-integral-sequence-i-n-int-011-x2ndx) is solved similarly using integration by parts. After some re-arranged in Eq. $(2)$, $$\left(2n+1\right)S_{n}=2nS_{n-1}+\frac{4^{n}n!^{2}}{\left(2n+1\right)!}$$ Let $S_{n}=P_{n}\cdot4^{n}n!^{2}/(2n+1)!$
$$P_{n}=P_{n-1}+\frac{1}{2n+1}=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{1}{2k+1}$$

And hence, $$S_n=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}\frac{(-1)^k}{(2k+1)^2}=\frac{4^{n}n!^{2}}{(2n+1)!}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{1}{2k+1}$$

---

Hints on solving the **second part** of the problem: Substitute Eq. $(1)$
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}\frac{(-1)^{k}}{(2k+1)^{2}}=-\int_{0}^{1}\ln\left(x\right)\cdot\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\left(1-x^{2}\right)^{n}}{n}\cdot dx$$

---

**Another method** using your integral:
$$\begin{align}S_{n}&=\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\left(1-x^{2}y^{2}\right)^{n}dydx\\&=2\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{y}\left(1-x^{2}y^{2}\right)^{n}dxdy\hspace{50pt}\text{..via symmetry}\\&=2\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}x\left(1-x^{4}z^{2}\right)^{n}dzdx\hspace{45pt}\text{..}y^2=x^2z^2\tag{3}\end{align}$$

Similaly via integration by parts, show
$$\begin{align}\int_{0}^{1}x\left(1-x^{4}z^{2}\right)^{n}dx&=\frac{(1-z^{2})^{n}}{2\left(2n+1\right)}+\frac{2n}{\left(2n+1\right)}\int_{0}^{1}x\left(1-x^{4}z^{2}\right)^{n-1}dx\\&=\frac{4^{n}n!^{2}}{\left(2n+1\right)!}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{2k}{k}\frac{(1-z^{2})^{k}}{2^{2k+1}}\tag{4}\end{align}$$
Substitute $(4)$ in $(3)$ and you'll reach the right-hand side.

Comment: Excellent work indeed !

Comment: I really appreciate for your excellent answer. I want to ask one more thing. I don’t understand the hint of second question, $\int_{0}^{1}\log x\cdot\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(1-x^{2})^{n}}{n}dx$ is the root of a monic polynomial?

Comment: @HyunSeokYi The first step is evaluating the sum inside the integral. We have the series expansion of $-\ln (1-x)=\sum_{n\ge1} x^n/n$ and hence, $\sum_{n \ge 1} (1-x^2)^n/n=-2\ln (x)$ And then we have $$-\int_{0}^{1}\ln\left(x\right)\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\left(x^{2}-1\right)^{n}}{n}dx=2\int_{0}^{1}\ln\left(x\right)^{2}dx$$

Comment: WOW! I really appreciate for your detail description. So this value is an integer, its amazing result!